# Error at word. SCARD_READERSTATE

Tags: vb.net, smartcard

i want declare function SCardGetStatusChange. but why i have error at word. SCARD_READERSTATE. error : type 'SCARD_READERSTATE' is not defined.

```
Public Declare Function SCardGetStatusChange Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardGetStatusChangeA" ( _
    ByVal hContext As Long, _
    ByVal dwTimeout As Long, _
    ByRef rgReaderStates() As SCARD_READERSTATE, _
    ByVal cReaders As Long _
    ) As Long
```

Comment: i'm using microsoft visual basic 2008

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer - you haven't in your code defined `SCARD_READERSTATE`. It is a seperate struct that you have to define.

Look at pinvoke.net for examples (see [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SCARD_READERSTATE.html)) or google it a bit.